# Was Bar Kochva disemboweled?

Tags: history, names, agada-stories-legends, maseches-gitin

The gemarah in Gittin, [57a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=57&format=pdf), details a story of "bar d'roma" who performs miraculous feats in defending the Jews before meeting his demise by being disemboweled by a snake (similar to the end of Bar Kochba in Yerushalmi ta'anis 4:5). I cannot find a source that identifies this nameless individual with the more famous Bar Kochva but the parallels seem striking. Is there an authority who puts the two together?

Comment: The מהרש"א on Gitta 57a IIRC says that the war of "Bar Daroma" was around the time of the Churban Beis Sheini, so seemingly not Bar Koziba (which in Seder Olam IIRC places it around 50 years or so after Churban)